# Show element with input button only with css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, forms, input

I want to show an section when the checkbox is checked on another section, and show it with an animation from the top. I have the following code for the input that is in another section .

```html
<div className="continue" id="first">
  <button className="btn-continue">
                    Contratar Plano
                    <input type="checkbox" id="reveal-email" role="button"/>
                  </button>

</div>

<section className="plan-section" id="plan-section">
  <div className="next">
    <i class="arrow down"></i>
  </div>
  <div className="form-block">
    <form className="form">
      <div className="plan-form">
        <div className="input-block">
          <label htmlFor="name">Nome</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onChange={props.handleChange} required className="input" />
        </div>

        <div className="continue">
          <button className="btn-continue" id="plan-continue" disabled={props.step.isLast()} onClick={props.next}>
                  <span className="btn-text">Contratar Plano</span>
                  <img className="check-btn" src={check} />
                </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Also showing the section I need to show; this section has a default `display:none`.

Comment: Why do you want to use only CSS, by your description this is  a `classic` JS task?

Comment: @Sergey-N13 I thought it would be simpler using css only, but accept js as well

Comment: Note that `<input>` (or `<input />`) is a self-closing tag, and has no corresponding `</input>` tag.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica yeah, I fixed that on the code

Comment: Is the `<button class=""btn-continue>` the `<button>` you want to click on to show the next `<section>`? Is that `<button>` in its own parent `<section>`, or just wrapped in the `<div>` which is a sibling of the `<section>` in your code Snippet?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica the <button> is on another <section> that is sibling of this, I'm using the input inside the <button> because I'm using multi-step forms from react, the only way that works is if I use <button>

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry to have to ask for more details but would you mind posting the the HTML that's in the DOM once the reactjs has finished, and show both of the `<section>` elements (the first with the `<button>` to activate/show the second)?

Answer (score 0):

One recommendation regarding your code:

```
<button className="btn-continue">
                    Contratar Plano
    <input type="checkbox" id="reveal-email" role="button"></input>
</button>
```

It's not a good practice to group checkbox and some text into button, in HTML you can use [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) for that.

If JS solution is acceptable, you need to follow these steps:

1. [Find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) your checkbox button and section in the DOM
2. [Add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) event listener which will trigger callback function after each change of the checkbox state
3. In the callback function you need to trigger [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style) for your section.

The full code is below:

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById('reveal-email');
var section = document.getElementById('plan-section');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', onChange)

function onChange() {
  if (this.checked) {
    section.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    section.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div className="continue" id="first">
  <button className="btn-continue">
    Contratar Plano
    <input type="checkbox" id="reveal-email" role="button"/>
  </button>
</div>

<section className="plan-section" id="plan-section" style="display:none">
  <div className="next">
    <i class="arrow down"></i>
  </div>
  <div className="form-block">
    <form className="form">
      <div className="plan-form">
        <div className="input-block">
          <label htmlFor="name">Nome</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onChange={props.handleChange} required className="input" />
        </div>

        <div className="continue">
          <button className="btn-continue" id="plan-continue" disabled={props.step.isLast()} onClick={props.next}>
            <span className="btn-text">Contratar Plano</span>
            <img className="check-btn" src={check} />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: even though your anwser is working, please also make the efford to explain why it is working or what the OP needs to do. Providing code is one thing, making them to understand the issue and solution is the way to go.

Comment: @tacoshy Yep, I agree with you, explanation more preferable than answer. I've updated my answer and also I'd like to recommend you to avoid using JS in HTML in your next answers, because many newbies developers can get it like a best practice.

Comment: @Sergey-N13 I tried your code but got the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: @PaolaSantos Did you paste JS this code to the TOP or BOTTOM of your page? If you paste JS code at the top of your page you need to wrap this code to window load event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: @Sergey-N13 I fixed that but still not working, the section still does no appear

Comment: @PaolaSantos if you use React you need to close this question and open new (width correct tags and more detailed description), because this is unclear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Its a classic JS task. Use an onclick event to check if the checkbox is checked and then to change the section from  `display: none`  to  `display: block` . Also Add an onclick event so that JS is triggered.

```js
function showSection() {
  var showSection = document.getElementById("reveal-email"),
      planSection = document.getElementById("plan-section");
  if (showSection.checked == true) {
    planSection.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    planSection.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#plan-section {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div className="continue" id="first">
  <button className="btn-continue">Contratar Plano
    <input type="checkbox" id="reveal-email" onclick="showSection()">
  </button>

</div>

<section className="plan-section" id="plan-section">
  <div className="next">
    <i class="arrow down"></i>
  </div>
  <div className="form-block">
    <form className="form">
      <div className="plan-form">
        <div className="input-block">
          <label htmlFor="name">Nome</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onChange={props.handleChange} required className="input" />
        </div>

        <div className="continue">
          <button className="btn-continue" id="plan-continue" disabled={props.step.isLast()} onClick={props.next}>
                  <span className="btn-text">Contratar Plano</span>
                  <img className="check-btn" src={check} />
                </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @tacshy I tried your solution but not work, I'm using multi-step from react and have a 4 step form, when I click the input nothing happens